# Twilio Client for android has no audio

Tags: twilio

I'm trying out the [Twilio Android Quickstart](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client), and I've gotten to the end of the [Making an outgoing call](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/make-outgoing-call) section, but for some reason. I'm not getting audio.

I'm able to see that the requests are going out to Twilio appropriately, because Twilio is accessing my app's voice request url. After a few seconds, I can see in LogCat that the `Connection disconnected successfully`.

I have a Nexus 4, and a Nexus 7 that I've been trying this out on, as well as the Android Emulator with similar results.

I tried the WebRTC Client in the browser, and my endpoint seems to work fine, so I'm running a little short on ideas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I contacted Twilio support about this issue, and it appears that outgoing calls using their API do no work correctly when it's still in the Trial account.

Twilio support moved my account up to a full account, and the problems went away.